# MySQL - selective removing duplicated records

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have db with few 1000 of contacts and would like to delete all duplicated records. Sql query I have at the moment works well ( when in records - **tel**, **email**, **name1** are duplicated). Query deletes duplicates with lower id then last occurring record. But in some cases another fields of the record a filled in already (important ones will by **title** and **name2**). What i would like to achieve is for mysql to check if these fields are filled in and keep only the record with most information filed in.

My Query

```
<?php

$del_duplicate_contacts = $mysqli->query("

DELETE  ca
FROM    contacts ca
     LEFT JOIN
  (
 SELECT MAX(id) id, name1, tel, email
            FROM    contacts
            GROUP   BY name1, tel, email
        ) cb ON  ca.id = cb.id AND 
                ca.name1 = cb.name1 AND
                ca.tel = cb.tel AND
                ca.email = cb.email
WHERE   cb.id IS NULL

");

?>
```

Example of table:

```
ID   title   name1   name2    tel      email
1            John             01234    1@1.com
2    Mr      John     Smith   01234    1@1.com
3            John             01234    1@1.com
```

My query will delete record 1 and 2. I would like to keep only nr 2 and delete 1 and 3. 
How I can achieve that? Is is possible? Or maybe i should involve PHP, if so How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` in `group_concat`, you can try this:

```
DELETE c1 FROM contacts c1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        substring_index(group_concat(id ORDER BY ((title IS NULL OR title ='') AND (name2 IS NULL OR name2 = '')), id DESC), ',', 1) AS id,
        name1, tel, email
    FROM contacts
    GROUP BY name1, tel, email
) c2
ON c1.name1 = c2.name1 AND c1.tel = c2.tel AND c1.email = c2.email AND c1.id <> c2.id;
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f70b/1)

Comment: removed 1st record only , but i think your previous version was working correctly

Comment: @Nita Do you check the demo in my answer, it only remained 2nd record.

Comment: yes, it is working as it should. Sorry, for late answer

Comment: @Nita Glad can help. :-D

Comment: Hi JPG. Do you think there is any way to make it work faster. On 30000 record mysql crushes. I had to divide data to chunks in order to complete task. Should be possible to run it once, right?

Answer (score 1):

OOPS - This is the worst answer I have produced so far -- warning the top bit is dangerous, not sure why I did not include any group -- **please continue to the bottom part, which is working now:**

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
    FROM contacts AS a
    JOIN contacts AS b
    ON  a.name1 = b.name1
    AND a.tel = b.tel
    AND a.email = b.email
    ORDER BY a.name1 DESC, a.name2 DESC, a.title DESC
    LIMIT 1,100000
  ) AS tmp
)
```

LIMIT Must be 1, xxxx -- not 0, xxxx to keep the first one undeleted

As you cannot delete directly from the same table found in sub-query, just add a mask layer, so it is now tested working

**Before** Deleting, always double check what is going to be deleted:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
    ...
    LIMIT 1,100000
  ) AS tmp
)
```

Apologies for the damage, luckily you did on a testing db

=====================================

Now here is the correct solution:

Let's check what is in the testing table:

[image]

According to question, we noticed only #2 #4 #5 is good to keep. And here is the result:

[image]

And we want to delete any records not in above list, before delete, we double check what is going to be deleted:

[image]

And we are ready to delete:

[image]

And here is the SQL, make sure you do on testing db first:

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID FROM (
      SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY title DESC, name1 DESC, name2 DESC, tel DESC, email DESC
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY name1, tel, email
  ) AS del
)
```

Comment: I corrected Order Ny to Order by. Still doesn't work

Comment: Error No: 1235 - MySQL error This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' .

Comment: My Server version: 5.7.11 is this possible?

Comment: Updated. Try again

Comment: this wipe out my contacts, so.. left 1 (:

Comment: Are you sure? I tested my db only deleted those matching your questions

Comment: Yes, have been doing some test and query wipes all the contact out except 1 with the highest id. Still thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works now, i will be doing speed test to compare it with other solution above. There is couple of thing i would like to improve, though! Thanks

Comment: What do you think  about deleting dangerous solution ?

Comment: Backup your table before delete, and you will be happy :D

Answer (score 1):

I have got solution using NOT EXIST clause instead of NOT IN

```
DELETE FROM contacts 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (
       SELECT * FROM ( 
          SELECT * FROM contact AS tmp ORDER BY title DESC, name1 DESC, name2 DESC, email DESC, tel DESC ) 
       as tbl group by name1) 
    as test WHERE contact.id= test.id 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work without any ordering options !

```
DELETE FROM contacts where ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM ( Select A.ID from contacts as A 
                    join contacts AS B 
                    ON A.name1 = B.name1 
                    AND A.name2 = B.name2
                    AND A.tel = B.tel 
                    AND A.email = B.email) As mytry);
```

Comment: Query wipes all the contact out except 1 with the highest id.